Gcloud cannot find module 'sequelize'
I must deploy my node.js + express rest api server and I chose google cloud's app engine standard environment. Locally my server work as I expected but when deploying on gcloud I always get the error "Cannot find module 'sequelize'". Sequelize is in the dependecies of my package.json and I can't figure out how to make it work.
//app.yaml

runtime: nodejs20
env: standard
instance_class: F2

env_variables:
  DB_HOST: 'localhost'
  DB_PORT: '3306'
  DB_USER: 'user'
  DB_PASSWORD: 'password'
  DB_DATABASE: 'seinfeld_episodes'
  DB_TEST_DATABASE: 'seinfeld_episode_test'
  GOOGLE_NODE_RUN_SCRIPTS: ''

package.json
{
  "name": "backend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "install-deps": "npm install",
    "gcp-build": "npm install",
    "build": "npm install",
    "start": "node ./index.js",
    "test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --testTimeout=5000"
  },
  "engines":{
    "node": "20.x"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.20.2",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "dotenv": "^16.4.5",
    "express": "^4.19.2",
    "faker": "^5.5.3",
    "jasmine-node": "^1.16.0",
    "joi": "^17.12.3",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "mysql2": "^3.9.6",
    "nodemon": "^3.1.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "sequelize-cli": "^6.6.2",
    "supertest": "^6.3.4",
    "uuid": "^9.0.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "chai": "^5.1.0",
    "jest": "^29.7.0",
    "mocha": "^10.4.0",
    "sequelize": "^6.37.3",
    "sequelize-mock": "^0.10.2",
    "sqlite": "^5.1.1",
    "sqlite3": "^5.1.7"
  }
}

also as for refference, this is where the file where the code breaks:
database.js
const Sequelize  = require('sequelize');
require('dotenv').config();

const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    dialect: 'mysql',
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: process.env.DB_PORT,
    database: process.env.DB_DATABASE,
    username: process.env.DB_USER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
});

module.exports = { sequelize };

and also the error log:
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 503
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1146
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]    throw err;
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]    ^
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  Error: Cannot find module 'sequelize'
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  Require stack:
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  - /workspace/database.js
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  - /workspace/models/episode.model.js
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  - /workspace/routes/episodes.route.js
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  - /workspace/app.js
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  - /workspace/index.js
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1143:15)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/database.js:1:20)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1427:10)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1206:32)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1022:12)
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19) {
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]    code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]    requireStack: [
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      '/workspace/database.js',
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      '/workspace/models/episode.model.js',
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      '/workspace/routes/episodes.route.js',
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      '/workspace/app.js',
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]      '/workspace/index.js'
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]    ]
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  }
2024-05-11 06:33:39 default[20240511t093202]  Node.js v20.12.2


I tried reinstalling the sequelize module, I kept updating the package.json file in hopes for gcloud to recognize the module but everything I did didn't seem to work.
